# How would I include the parent description in the main description column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query:

```
SELECT
    Object.Description,
    categories.Description AS ParentDescription
FROM ObjectInspectionLog oil
INNER JOIN Object ON oil.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId
INNER JOIN Object as categories ON Object.ParentId = categories.ObjectId
WHERE oil.Notes IS NULL
GROUP BY Object.Description, categories.Description
ORDER BY MIN(Object.ObjectId)
```

**FYI: My actual naming does not use the name *object***

`ObjectInspectionLog`:

```
ObjectInspectionLogId   JobId   ObjectId    Notes
3,  6669,   15, NULL    
4,  6669,   2,  NULL    
5,  6669,   3,  Rear tires worn 
6,  6669,   4,  NULL    
7,  6669,   5,  NULL    
8,  6669,   14, NULL
```

`Object`

```
ObjectId    ParentId    Description
1,  NULL,   Chassis
2,  1,  Front Tires
3,  1,  Rear Tires
4,  1,  Windshield Condition
5,  1,  Headlights
13, NULL,   Adaptive Equipment
14, 13, Occupied Wheelchair Lift
15, 14, Dual post lift
```

Currently, what I get returned looks something like this:
(removed some information for brevity)

```
Description ParentDescription
Windshield Condition,   Chassis
Headlights, Chassis
Occupied Wheelchair Lift,   Adaptive Equipment
ETC
```

My goal is to get a list *including* the parent description (Chassis, Adaptive Equipment, etc)
What I want returned is this:

```
Description ParentDescription
Chassis, NULL
Windshield Condition,   Chassis
Headlights, Chassis
Adaptive Equipment, NULL
Occupied Wheelchair Lift,   Adaptive Equipment
ETC
```

Comment: your issue is not clear.I think your data is wrong.pleas review them.

Comment: @somayejavidmoradi What specifically is not clear? I would be happy to fix or add information.

Comment: for example "Chassis, NULL" is for objectId=1 in table object while there is not this objectID in ObjectInspectionLog

Comment: I think ObjectInspectionLog's Data is not correct

Comment: @somayejavidmoradi It is correct, the parents are never included in the InspectionLog, just the children.

Comment: it is not clear the result that you want is on what base.why "Front Tires,Chassis" is not in your result?

Comment: @somayejavidmoradi Clarified my post: "My goal is to get a list including the parent description (`Chassis, Adaptive Equipment, etc`)"

Comment: what is difference between objectId 2,4?why you have (Windshield Condition,   Chassis) in result.but you have not (Front Tires,Chassis)?

Comment: @somayejavidmoradi There is no difference, I just removed things from my results as to not make the post longer than it needed to be

Comment: If you want to have a `join` that produces rows from one table even when there is no match in the other table then you want an `outer join`, not an `inner join`. Note that references to the "missing" data in the `where` clause must allow for `NULL` values or it will effectively convert the `outer join` to an `inner join`.

Comment: @HABO What would an update where clause to allow  `null` look like?

Comment: `select * from Object as Child left outer join Object as Parent on Parent.ObjectId = Child.ParentId and Parent.Description like '%favorite%';` is equivalent to `select * from Object as Child left outer join Object as Parent on Parent.ObjectId = Child.ParentId where Parent.Description like '%favorite%' or Parent.Description is NULL;`. The `on` clause expects `NULL` values from the right side of the `left outer join`. If the condition `Parent.Description like '%favorite%'` is moved from the `on` to the `where` clause then it needs to explicitly allow for `NULL`s.

Comment: That didn't work for me, the parent was never included in the return with the children. Also, as per my original post, I still need the Parents returned in another column.

Comment: @jfiggins The queries in my comment were in answer to your comment, not the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well,you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT obj.description,categories.description
FROM Object obj
LEFT JOIN Object as categories ON obj.ParentId = categories.ObjectId
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM ObjectInspectionLog oil
    INNER JOIN Object obj2 ON oil.ObjectId = obj2.ObjectId
    WHERE oil.Notes IS NULL
    AND obj.ObjectId in ( obj2.ObjectId, obj2.parentId)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to output rows for objects whether or not they are referenced by the `ObjectInspectionLog`, e.g. `ObjectId` `1` should produce an output row. It's not clear why you are using `group by`.

The following code uses `outer` joins to come closer to what you might want:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @ObjectInsopectionLog as Table ( ObjectInspectionLogId Int, JobId Int, ObjectId Int, Notes VarChar(32) );

insert into @ObjectInsopectionLog ( ObjectInspectionLogId, JobId, ObjectId, Notes ) values
  ( 3,  6669,   15, NULL ),
  ( 4,  6669,   2,  NULL ),
  ( 5,  6669,   3,  'Rear tires worn' ),
  ( 6,  6669,   4,  NULL ),
  ( 7,  6669,   5,  NULL ),
  ( 8,  6669,   14, NULL );

select * from @ObjectInsopectionLog;

declare @Objects as Table ( ObjectId Int, ParentId Int, Description VarChar(32) );

insert into @Objects ( ObjectId, ParentId, Description ) values
  ( 1,  NULL, 'Chassis' ),
  ( 2,  1, 'Front Tires' ),
  ( 3,  1, 'Rear Tires' ),
  ( 4,  1, 'Windshield Condition' ),
  ( 5,  1, 'Headlights' ),
  ( 13, NULL, 'Adaptive Equipment' ),
  ( 14, 13, 'Occupied Wheelchair Lift' ),
  ( 15, 14, 'Dual post lift' );

select * from @Objects;

-- Do the work.
select Child.Description, Parent.Description as ParentDescription, OIL.ObjectId as OIL_ObjectId
  from @ObjectInsopectionLog as OIL full outer join -- Return all rows from either side of this   join .
    @Objects as Child on Child.ObjectId = OIL.ObjectId left outer join -- Return all   Child   rows regardless of   Parent .
    @Objects as Parent on Parent.ObjectId = Child.ParentId
  where OIL.Notes is NULL
  order by Child.ObjectId;
```